# Batch rename file using for loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to use a for loop to rename a file

```
::@Echo Off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
::Set Date
set mydate=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
::Rename file
for %%F in (D:\Data\*.bak) do (
    ren %%F D:\Data\prod_live_Full_%mydate%0000.Lts.bak
)
```

I keep getting invalid command error.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If there is more than one .bak file in d:\data isn't this going to try to rename them all the exact same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When modifying files in a directory use a static file list from `dir` instead of a dynamic file list from `for`.  Otherwise, you will get stuck in an infinite loop.

```
@echo Off
setlocal
set "mydate=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%"
pushd "D:\Data\" && for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /a-d /b *.bak') do (
    ren "%%~fA" "prod_live_Full_%mydate%0000.Lts.bak"
)
popd
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

The error was caused by your second parameter to the `ren` command.  It is only expecting a new file name, not a full path and file name.  The `ren` command cannot move files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your date format, but if the logic of date cut is not correct (in my pc, in spanish, it doesn't work) the mydate variable can contain a slash, which is not allowed in a file name.

If there are more than one file, ren will fail, as all the rename operations try to use the same file name.