# cmd for loop mass renaming again oneliner

Tags: for-loop, cmd, batch-rename, variable-expansion

I'm over my head with this - spent too much time searching already - evidently I don't understand the basics of CMD variables etc. - and it always gives me such a headache

why wouldn't this work?

`for %a in (*) do ( set tmpx=%a & echo %tmpx% )`

the above code outputs the value of %tmpx% in some other scope - and it is always constant

yes, i run setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

basically i need to do a simple rename of all files in folder from constantstring_somenameXX.tif to somenameXX.tif, where i.e. constantstring=0000000005

i had to use set because other posts rightly suggested that %a in a for loop has a special behaviour, and the substitutions wouldn't work for it as it is.

i would prefer not to use scripts and/or powershell - unless not using them is impossible

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch rename file using for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453995/batch-rename-file-using-for-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for %a in (*) do ( set tmpx=%a & echo %tmpx% )
```

The problem with the previous code is delayed expansion. Yes, you enabled it, but you have not used it, and depending on how you enabled it, it will not work

In `cmd`, when a line or block of lines (code inside parenthesis) is reached, it is first parsed and then executed. During the parse phase, variable read operations are removed from the command, replaced with the value in the variable *before* the command starts to execute. So, if you change the value of a variable inside a line/block you can not retrieve the changed value inside the same line/block as there are no variable reads (they were replaced)

`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` allows to replace (where needed) the variable read syntax from `%var%` to `!var!`, indicating to the parser that the read operation will be delayed until the execution phase.

So, in your case, your code should have been something like

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & for %a in (*) do ( set "tmpx=%a" & echo !tmpx! )
```

BUT this will not work (in default configured environments).

`cmd` has two execution modes: batch file and command line. In your case, you are using command line (no escaped percent sign in `for` loop) and in command line mode the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` will not work. It is intended for batch files (see `setlocal /?`)

How to make it work from the command line? By default `cmd` is started with delayed expansion disabled and you can not enable it if not inside a batch file. But you can start `cmd` with delayed expansion enabled and run your command in this started instance (see `cmd /?`)

```
cmd /v:on /c "for %a in (*) do ( set "tmpx=%a" & echo !tmpx! )"
```

Anyway, to solve your rename problem, delayed expansion is not needed

```
for %a in (*_*.tif) do for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %b in ("%~nxa") do echo ren "%a" "%c"
```

That is, for each `tif` file with an underscore, take the name and extension of the file (`%~nxa`) as a string, and using the underscore as a delimiter between tokens, retrieve the first token (the text on the left of the first underscore) in `%b` and the rest of the text (to the right of the underscore) into `%c`. Now, just rename the original file name (stored in `%a`) to the contents of `%c` (the text on the right of the underscore)

In this code rename operations are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command.

Comment: thank you for your patience and thorough explanation - i used options like cmd /k and cmd /x but never looked actually at cmd /? to see how you enable it - in combination with the mysterious syntax of CMD/XP commands it all just frustrated me beyond hope

Answer (score -1):

! is the character to use rather than % when wanting execution time value. % does when it's read value.

CMD was written by IBM engineers and they were trying to make MSDos a programming language while making sure Dos commands ran the same. So we get a hodge podge.

```
&    seperates commands on a line.

&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

>    output to a file

>>    append output to a file

<    input from a file

|    output of one command into the input of another command

^    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program

"    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes

+ used with copy to concatinate files. E.G. copy file1+file2 newfile

, used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files modified date. E.G. copy /b file1,,

%variablename% a inbuilt or user set environmental variable

!variablename! a user set environmental variable expanded at execution time, turned with SelLocal EnableDelayedExpansion command

%<number> (%1) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file. %0 is the batchfile's name.

%* (%*) the entire command line.

%<a letter> or %%<a letter> (%A or %%A) the variable in a for loop. Single % sign at command prompt and double % sign in a batch file.
```