# Adding prefix to filenames in a folder in Windows 10

Tags: filenames

I want to add a prefix to all the files in one folder. I tried the following command:

`for %F in (*) do ren "%F" "Zer_%~nxF"`.

It creates an endless loop of adding the prefix over and over.  Can anyone suggest a correction?

Comment: What language/environment are you trying to do this is in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch rename file using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453995/batch-rename-file-using-for-loop)

Comment: Command Prompt in Windows 10. It workS OK once in  a while.